# Restrict users such that they will not copy or cut and paste a "Negative" number in a textbox from other textbox ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, textbox

I have the following code to allow only one negative symbol and also negative numbers.

But my user did a testing and said she can copy/cut -ve values from one textbox to another. Ideally, they shouldn't be allowed to copy/cut and paste a negative number from a textbox to aother textbox, but, if the number is positive, then allow them to cut/copy and paste.

I have to do this only in Javascript as I already have validation function on keypress event for textbox in JS. I use a hidden field for getting values from server side on when to do my logic.

```
function numbersOnly(Sender,evt,isFloat,isNegative) {
        if(Sender.readOnly) return false;       

        var key   = evt.which || !window.event ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        var value = Sender.value;

        console.log(key);

         if (value[0] != '-' && key != 45) return false;
          if (value[0] == '-' && key == 45) return false;

        if((key == 46 || key == 44) && isFloat){   
            var selected = document.selection ? document.selection.createRange().text : "";
            if(selected.length === 0 && value.indexOf(".") == -1 && value.length > 0) Sender.value += ".";
            return false;
        }
        if(key == 45) { // minus sign '-'
            if(!isNegative) return false;
            if(value.indexOf('-')== -1) Sender.value = '-'+value; else Sender.value = value.substring(1);
            if(Sender.onchange != null) {
                if(Sender.fireEvent){
                    Sender.fireEvent('onchange');
                } else {
                    var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
                        e.initEvent('change', false, false);
                    Sender.dispatchEvent(e);
                }
            }

            var begin = Sender.value.indexOf('-') > -1 ? 1 : 0;
            if(Sender.setSelectionRange){
                Sender.setSelectionRange(begin,Sender.value.length);
            } else {
                var range = Sender.createTextRange();
                range.moveStart('character',begin);
                range.select();                 
            }

            return false;
        }
        if(key > 31 && (key < 48 || key > 57)) return false;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated to modify the above function for restricting a number to be copied or cut and past if it is negative.

Comment: not certain, but could you validate on the onchange event of the textbox? basically, if textbox's value < 0, set textbox's value to blank?

Comment: That is an approach, I need to check though. I checked onupdate, it didnt work at all. So, currently I am returning false for oncut, onc opy and onpaste. I need to call same function like above in the onchange, I will check this.

Comment: actually no, apparently it would have to be in onpaste (unless you want to do "onpaste=this.onchange()"). and you said it doesn't fire there?

Comment: @Robert: No, onupdate doesnt work. I need to check this in onpaste

Comment: But I think it wont work on onpaste as apparently we check keypress events in the function above.

Comment: @Robert: It doesn't work or throwing this event at all on change.