# How to check if a value is negative and restrict from pasting it in a textbox on past CTRL+V or right click past

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, validation, textbox

I have few textboxes, where my requirement is, if a copied value by ctrl+C and or rightclick copy or right click and cut or ctrl+x is negative, then do not allow to paste this value in the other textbox when I do "ctrl+V" or right click and paste

```
function isNumberKeyForNegativePayments(Sender, evt) {
        //remove this code. always allow users to input negative amount
        //var controlId= 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hfAllowNegativeDeduction';
        //var er = document.getElementById(controlId);
        //            if (er.value == 1)
        //            {
        //                charLimit = 45; // allow negative
        //            }


        var charLimit = 45;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
        var value = Sender.value;

        if (value.indexOf('-') != -1 && charCode == 45) return false;
        if (value.indexOf('.') != -1 && charCode == 46) return false;
        if (value !== '' && value[0] != '-' && charCode == 45 && value.charCodeAt(value.length-1) == 45) return false;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 45 || charCode > 57)) return false;
        if (charCode > 46 && charCode < 48) return false;    

        var resultAllowNegativePayments = document.getElementById('<%=allowNegativePayments.ClientID%>').value;
        if (resultAllowNegativePayments === "true") {
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode < charLimit || charCode > 46))
            { 
                return false; 
            }
            else
            {
                var value = Sender.value;

                if (value.indexOf('-') != -1 && charCode == 45) return false;
                if (value.indexOf('.') != -1 && charCode == 46) return false;
                if (value !== '' && value[0] != '-' && charCode == 45 && value.charCodeAt(value.length-1) == 45) return false;
                if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 45 || charCode > 57)) return false;
                if (charCode > 46 && charCode < 48) return false;           
            }
        }
        else {
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) && (charCode < 46 || charCode > 46)) return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Do you want to go for html5, using the Min value for a numeric input type, javascript to detect onchange/onblur method, custom usercontrol to do the validations?

Comment: @Icepickle: lol firstly I liked your name :p icepickle :p lol Well I have updated my validation I did. But onchange doesnt work. My simple idea is to figure out the value in copied and if the value contains - symbol, then return false while pasting using right click or ctrl+v

Comment: Is it not a duplicate of [Restrict users such that they will not copy or cut and paste a "Negative" number in a textbox from other textbox ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743496/restrict-users-such-that-they-will-not-copy-or-cut-and-paste-a-negative-number)

Answer (score 0):

In the snippet, i created a small validator, that also keeps the last valid value, so it can restore the last correct value in case an invalid change was detected.

The validator just needs to be attached to the TextBox after the document was loaded, and it validates the textbox by use of an anonymous function as an argument for the ns.TextBox.Validator (you have to use the constructor though)

I guess strictly spoken, the rightmouse click paste would still be visible until the user either clicks on another field, or presses a key, then the last valid value would be restored in case the pasted one isn't good.

To check if it is a valid number, i used the parseInt + checking if a field is not simply empty (that might be valid)

By using the type number and minimum value set to 0, the input field also gets a red border

```js
;
(function(ns) {


  ns.TextBox = ns.TextBox || {
    Validator: function(element, evalValid) {
      this.element = document.getElementById(element);
      this.validator = evalValid.bind(this.element);
      this._currentValue = this.element.value;

      this.register = function() {
        var register = this.element.addEventListener || this.element.attachEvent,
            prepend = this.element.addEventListener ? '' : 'on',
            that = this,
            fnValidator = function(e) {
            if (that.element.value != that._currentValue) {
              if (!that.validator(e)) {
                that.element.value = that._currentValue;
                return false;
              }
              that._currentValue = that.element.value;
            }
            return true;
            };
        console.log(register);
        register.apply(this.element, [prepend + 'change', fnValidator]);
        register.apply(this.element, [prepend + 'keyup', fnValidator]);
        
        return this;
      }
    }
  };

}(window));

window.onload = function() {
  console.log('window loaded');
  var tbValidator = new window.TextBox.Validator('canNotHaveNegative', function() {
    console.log('parsing ' + this.value);
    return this.value == '' || parseInt(this.value) >= 0;
  });
  console.log(tbValidator);
  tbValidator.register();
};
```

```html
<div>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="canHaveNegative">Can have negative</label>
    <input type="number" id="canHaveNegative" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="canNotHaveNegative">Cannot have negative</label>
    <input type="number" id="canNotHaveNegative" min="0" title="must be a positive number" />
  </fieldset>
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit me</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not my issue and not the answer I am looking for. I have already the logic to disallow or allow negatives based on business requirements using hiddenvalue from server. I, however, need to disallow negative number pasting in textbox ONLY when that textbox shouldn't have or allow negative values on instance  on keypress events

Comment: I thought the issue was that you didn't want any negative values inside a textbox? The onload function sets the requirement only on the designated textbox, and automatically restores the last valid value inside the textbox, the pasting from rightclick gets reversed once you exit the textbox? Maybe my naming was false?

Comment: No icepickle, the requirement is very simple. I have few textboxes and the "BUSINESS requirements" to either allow or disallow negative values based on some scenarios, all good, I could achieve it via javascript function I pasted above. However, the copy/cut and paste does allow negatives to be copied and pasted while the business scenarios are that textbox shouldn't allow negatives on keypress. I want to achieve this.

Comment: All what I can do is, to return false on oncut,oncopy and onpaste. This will not allow copy cut paste blindly, although my client is fine with this, I feel its a stupid way to resolve problem, because, I feel they should be allowed to copy/cut/paste positive values no matter the business logics. My simple solution is, check the value copied/cut and see if it contains negative, don't allow. Ideally it shouldn't allow only when scenarios in keypress dont allow,  but its ok if we can achieve to the extent that if we dont allow copyu/cut/paste no matter business scenarios

Comment: This worked for me :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311927/do-not-allow-paste-any-non-alphanumeric-characters

Answer (score 0):

Below snipet will sort out the issue you facing, whatever you copying the value from one textbox to other textbox say "textBox2" if it is negative value it won't allow to paste..

```
   private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text.Contains('-'))
        {
            textBox2.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("Negative Value not allowed");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mate, that is as easy as you told, however, I am looking for that in the javascript and from aspx asp.net controls. Do you have an answer?